# How Do I Dual boot Windows After Ubuntu in Legacy mode GPT paritition Table?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags

1      1049kB  370GB  370GB   primary   ext4            boot

3      370GB   496GB  126GB   primary   ntfs

2      496GB   500GB  4198MB  extended

5      496GB   500GB  4198MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

Okay so basically I have my ubuntu on Legacy boot secure mode off: and I have created another partition of 126GB(ntfs) for my dual boot windows, However when I started to boot windows, I had an error message: Your partition table is MBR. The disk is in EFI system, and you need to convert it to GPT from MBR. I think it's maybe I have installed ubuntu on Legacy and I am installing windows on UEFI maybe? Now in order to convert MBR to GPT I need to erase all data and I would want to avoid that, So can I run both ubuntu and Windows on legacy GPT ?

Comment: You can convert a drive, but will need extra partitions. But gpt does not have primary, extended & logical issues. BIOS & UEFI Windows partitions, note system has totally different format  & meaning between BIOS & UEFI
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898504%28v=vs.85%29.aspx & 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn898510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations & Converting to or from GPT
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html

Answer (score 0):

It's windows that requires Legacy on an MBR disc or UEFI on a GPT disc. Ubuntu doesn't care as long as you have the right partition types. An EFI partition for a UEFI boot or a bio-grub for a legacy boot on a gpt disk.